# Professor claims two distinct maximum flows implies an "infinite number of maximum flows"

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

I will say right out that this is a homework problem that I have attempted for hours and I am not getting anywhere.  The problem states "Suppose there exist two distinct maximum flows *f₁* and *f₂*. Show that there exist infinitely many maximum flows."  Now, I needed some clarification on what he meant by distinct and the email reply I received stated, "*f₁* and *f₂* are distinct if there exists *(u,v)* such that *f₁(u,v) ≠ f₂(u,v)*."  So going off of this definition of distinct, I find the problem statement to not be true.

Take for example this graph:

[image: example graph]

It has two distinct maximum flows but no more.  What do you guys think?  Maybe I am going about this is the wrong way.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question and your sample graph.  If those are capacities on your edges, and you're trying to achieve max flow from A to D, isn't the max flow 1 because of the common A-B bottleneck? How does your graph represent two distinct max flows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If F_1 and F_2 are two maximal flows, then pick any 0 < lambda < 1. Then lambda * F_1 + (1 - lambda) * F_2 is also maximal. This yields an infinite family of maximal flows.

Perhaps your mistake is that you're thinking that flow along a particular edge has to be integral?

Comment: Right.  That was my mistake. I was under the assumption that a flow had to be an integer but when you consider that a flow can be any non-negative real number, it becomes quite easy.  Thank you for the clarification!